# Entity Framework pipeline: Expression trees to ESQL to SQL?

Tags: entity-framework

What is the Entity Framework pipeline like?
What gets translated to SQL, Expression Trees or ESQL, or both?
Is ESQL something an Entity Framework provider needs to implement or translate, or that the framework takes care of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Entity SQL and LINQ expressions are parsed into a common cannonical query tree which is then parsed to generate the provider specific SQL.

Jim Wooley

[www.ThinqLinq.com](http://www.ThinqLinq.com)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFSampleProvider) provider source [code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFOracleProvider)?